Where do VS Code download custom widgets for Jupyter Notebooks?
Recently I've downloaded some Jupyter notebook. It was from an unknown source, but code looked fine (no indicators of it being malicious), so I've run the notebook on my computer with VS Code.
However, what I've missed was the fact that this notebook had some widgets in it, so at first run VS Code said that "widgets require us to download supporting files from a 3rd party website". I've clicked ok, but now I have some doubts. To what folder was this "3rd party code" downloaded, and how can I review/delete it? Thanks!

Ok, thanks to IPyWidgets documentation (loading section) https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Component:-IPyWidgets
I found out that widgets are actually downloaded not to VSCode folder (system-level), but to active python environment. So it looks like the containing folder is <env_name>/share/jupyter/ (at least at this folder there are some subfolders with suitable names that was created at the same time i downloaded this widget)
I am not sure are this folders the only folders created for this widget, at least i hope so :) Will be grateful for any additional info\answers

It looks like you need to install the python package.
You could use command pip install packageName in the terminal to install python package.
In your case, you could run pip install ipywidgets to install this module.
